# sp2010 - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a WebApplication which I extended using CA and made the extension anonymous authorization (it's the RO version of the site).

After deploying my solution, whenever I try to access any page on the site (back or front) I get the error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

with trace

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web) +218
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context) +520
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext context) +27
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea) +918
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

However, when accessing a WCF (from the same solution) everything works fine.
Again this only happens on the extended RO version, normal RW WebApplication works perfectly.

When debugging, i stopped at Application_Start and started to go line by line, once I reached the end and pressed F10 to step over the next function, got the error.

Any Ideas?

With kind regards,
Nadav